# Laravel - Get error message from localized file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating my own validation and need to retrieve error messages from the localized file(resources/lang/en/validation.php and etc). The main task is to get array of error messages from the appropriate file. Usually, the validator does it and you don't need to worry about it. Does exist a way to get all these messages with no using validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access your translation files and their contents from anywhere with the global helper function `trans`
For example: your translations are in the file resources/lang/en/customvalidation.php

```
return [
    'customerror' => 'my custom error message',
];
```

Then

```
trans('customvalidation.customerror')
```

will return "my custom error message" (depending on the current set language)